# Disabling "MyApp has stopped working" dialog

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-registry

When an application crashes on Windows Server 2008 SP1, I get this message box:

```
MyApp has stopped working
Windows is searching for a solution...
```

How can I prevent this message box from appearing?

**Update**: What I really need is to make no dialog appear. I have formulated my real intent in [another question](https://serverfault.com/questions/30177/disabling-process-crash-dialogs-on-vista).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To completely disable this message box, set the registry value (HKLM or HKCU)\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\DontShowUI to 1.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513638%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean how can you stop the application from crashing or how can you stop the message from displaying when it does?

If the former, then without any information about the application we're not going to be able to help.  The latter I believe can only be dealt withby gracefully handling the error within the application code AFAIK.

Comment: Of course the latter.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is controlled by "windows error reporting service", at least, in Vista. It might be called something else in 2008