# Disabling process crash dialogs on Vista

Tags: windows-vista

A sequel of [Disabling "MyApp has stopped working" dialog](https://serverfault.com/questions/29678/disabling-myapp-has-stopped-working-dialog).

What can I do so that no dialog appears when a process crashes?

Update: If Windows Error Reporting is disabled, the dialog says "A problem has caused the program to stop working correctly" and has a "Close the program" button.

Comment: What dialog does appear when WER is disabled?

Comment: A problem has caused the program to stop working correctly.
And a "Close the program" button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the registry, go to key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting` and add the REG_DWORD value DontShowUI = 1

[Source](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winservergen/thread/8e7a7f48-a65e-4cd5-a55a-a62e4f7604cc?prof=required&ppud=4)